# Getting execution bytecode from trace_addresses

Tags: evm, bytecode, openethereum, transaction-trace, trace

Given the following call graph:

```
A
  CALLs B
    CALLs G
  CALLs C
    CALLs G
```

Is it possible to get the **full bytecode** that was executed by the evm as a single string, given the bytecode of the contracts and the parity trace_addresses or do I need more information for that?

Essentially I am trying to do something like this:

```
def extract_executed_bytecode(trace_addresses, contract_bytecodes):
    # help
    return executed_bytecode

trace_addresses = [
    {'A': []},
    {'B': [0]},
    {'G': [0, 0]},
    {'C': [1]},
    {'G': [1, 0]}
]
contract_bytecodes = {
    'A': '0x6060604052600a8060106000396000f360606040526008565b00',
    'B': '0x6060604052600b8060106000396000f360606040526009565b00',
    'C': '0x6060604052600c8060106000396000f36060604052600a565b00',
    'G': '0x6060604052600d8060106000396000f36060604052600b565b00'
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on "full bytecode"? Are you looking for what opcodes are ran by EVM during a certain call?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use the Ethereum.traces table within Dune, or a spell if you're looking for something in particular. Since a single transaction can spawn multiple requests, you can group by the tx_hash and then work from there.

Feel free to ask around in the Dune discord as well.

Here's a simple example query: https://dune.com/queries/38730